# Second checkout of the same local Git branch?

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to have a more than one checkout of the same local branch, in the same way you can checkout a remote branch?

1. Checked out a remote repo
2. Branched locally
3. Committed some changes locally to my new branch

Now I need a second folder that is an exact copy of my branch without the build artifacts. Ideally I would check it out again.

I don't want to push to remote, since my branches are just experiments.
My understanding is that the local git repo just covers one folder (where it is located), so it is not possible.

Comment: How about [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)?

Comment: Or how about `cp -a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a more than one checkout of the same local branch

Yes you can. Use the `git worktree add` and create a second copy of your workspace with any desired branch

```
git worktree add <new_path>
```

then checkout any branch in the new location (can even be the same branch and work on it)